# Reaction of electromagnetic radiations with the air pollutants

Tags: everyday-chemistry, environmental-chemistry, electromagnetic-radiation

My friends, who are working on an IoT based technology project, explained their idea to me which is roughly like **reducing air pollution** by converting pollutants to oxygen ($\ce{O2}$) in any reaction, using waves and in particular microwaves. I have two questions in mind:

1. How do waves such as infrared, ultraviolet, microwave and others react with pollutants or in general with a gaseous mixture?
2. Which electromagnetic waves would be better in terms of factors such as time, temperature, rate of reaction and cost?

The pollutant mixture may contain all the pollutants described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_pollution#Pollutants), but the project is much more concerned with those that are more harmful than others to humans and life on earth.

Comment: I believe irradiation of $\ce{NO2}$ could convert it to $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{O}$. Don't know how much that will help - it might make ozone.